# Vagrant failing on document root

Tags: php, bash, vagrant

I am trying to set up a new Vagrant box. My bash script looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "--- Good morning, master. Let's get to work. Installing now. ---"

echo "--- Updating packages list ---"
sudo apt-get update

echo "--- MySQL time ---"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'

echo "--- Installing base packages ---"
sudo apt-get install -y vim curl python-software-properties

echo "--- Updating packages list ---"
sudo apt-get update

echo "--- We want the bleeding edge of PHP, right master? ---"
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5

echo "--- Updating packages list ---"
sudo apt-get update

echo "--- Installing PHP-specific packages ---"
sudo apt-get install -y php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql git-core

echo "--- Installing and configuring Xdebug ---"
sudo apt-get install -y php5-xdebug

cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
EOF

echo "--- Enabling mod-rewrite ---"
sudo a2enmod rewrite

echo "--- Setting document root ---"
sudo rm -rf /var/www
sudo ln -fs /vagrant/public /var/www


echo "--- What developer codes without errors turned on? Not you, master. ---"
sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

echo "--- Restarting Apache ---"
sudo service apache2 restart

echo "--- Composer is the future. But you knew that, did you master? Nice job. ---"
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

echo "--- All set to go! Would you like to play a game? ---"
```

Although when I run `vagrant up` in the terminal I get this error

```
--- What developer codes without errors turned on? Not you, master. ---
--- Restarting Apache ---
* Restarting web server apache2
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www] does not exist
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
...done.
```

I have searched using the finder for /var/www and I am taken to the correct folder. The permissions for this folder are set at `755`

Why would it fail in finding the document root?

Answer (score 0):

I may be not right but I feel lines

```
echo "--- Setting document root ---"
sudo rm -rf /var/www
sudo ln -fs /vagrant/public /var/www
```

is giving you issue

`/vargrant/public` rights should be also fine

if I were to opt I could have not removed /var/www

also symbolic links safe for me would be

```
sudo ln -fs  /var/www /vagrant/public
```

Atleast you will not find same error

other points which perks me is why can't you set virtual host directory to `/vagrant/public` path in apache.conf file

say append file with

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /vagrant/public
ServerName somenameorip

</VirtualHost>
```